# Windows "hosts" file directs my Laravel virtual host to IIS, i.e., port 80, instead of Apache, i.e., port 8080. How can I fix this?

Tags: php, apache, iis, laravel-5

I have already installed Laravel PHP framework, created a virtual host, and pointed that virtual host to  "C:/xampp/htdocs/laraveldev/public" in Apache "httpd-vhosts.conf" file as follows:

```
`NameVirtualHost *:8080
`<VirtualHost *:8080>  
`DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
`ServerName localhost
`</VirtualHost>
`<VirtualHost *:8080>
   `DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/laraveldev/public"
   `ServerName laraveldev 
`</VirtualHost>
```

In Windows "hosts" file I typed:

```
`127.0.0.1     laraveldev
```

I have Apache listening on port 8080 and IIS on port 80.  Windows "hosts" file directs laraveldev to port 80, i.e., IIS rather than directing it  to port 8080, i.e., Apache.  Can anyone help?  Thanks.

Comment: The host file does not direct to a port.  When you use `http://` the browser assumes the standard port 80.  To use another port you need `http://laraveldev:8080`

Comment: The port apache is listening on is 8080 so you have to use the port in the URL. You **can't** have two services using the same port. It's one or the other.

Comment: AbraCadaver, I typed http://laraveldev:8080, but it goes to google search result.

Comment: Panam Jack, What do you mean?  I have been trying to use port 8080, but it goes to port 80.

Comment: I mean the same thing AbraCadaver said. You can't have 2 services listening on the same port. If you already have IIS on 80 then you have to use another port. You've chosen 8080. Now you have to access the site that way. `http://laraveldev:8080` however I would use your IP address of your machine instead of `127.0.0.1` in the hosts file.

Comment: I typed http://laraveldev:8080/.  It did work.   Thanks.

Comment: Actually the file is `hosts` not `host` and it is in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\

Comment: Sorry for the typing error.  I try to fix it.